# javascript initialize object property

Tags: javascript, object, methods, initializing

This is going to be stupid, but... I for the life of me can't figure out how to initialize all the methods of an object.
For instance

```
var obj = {
prop1: function() { ... },
prop2: function() { ... } //etc
}
```

Can't figure out how to initialize them without calling
obj.prop1() and obj.prop2(), which would be vary tedious if I have ya'know 10+ functions.
I've also looked at something like,

```
var obj = new obj();

function obj() {
    this.init=function() { ... };
    this.init();
}
```

However, as far as I can tell, again, I'd have to initialize each one independently.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you would ever need to initialize 10 different things for a single object.

One way to do this is hide all the calls in a single init method, but you would still have to run all 10 methods from there.

The other way is to name all initializing methods something special like `__initMyCustomInit`.
After that you can loop over all the properties of the object and match `__init` using the regex `^__init.*$`

```
for (var prop in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop.match(/^__init.*$/)) {
    obj[prop]();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand fully what you want but this could work:

```
var obj = {

prop1: function() { return true; },
prop2: function() { return false; }

}
//init
for(var r in obj){
      obj[r](); // call!
}
```

Or as part of your obj:

```
var obj = {
  prop1: function() { return true; },
  prop2: function() { return false; },
  init: function() {
     for(var r in this){
         //prevent calling your self...
         if (r!=='init'){
           this[r]();
         }
     } 
  }   
}

obj.init();
```

Comment: This init method you use here, you only use for singleton objects like above? I assume when you are not using singleton objects, such as when you want inheritance, you would use the new syntax e.g. var obj = new MyObject();